# How to find a string on document and then echo the string?

Tags: php, string, document, file-get-contents

How do you find a string on document and then echo the string?

For example,

The document:

```
blah blah result.php?whatiwanttoecho blah
```

or:

```
blahhh result.php?whatiwanttoecho blah blah blah
```

There will always be 'result.php?' before what I want to echo.

The end result I'm looking for:

```
$doc = "./doc.txt";

$doccontents = file_get_contents($file);
```

Then the code that I need help that has the end result of:

```
$result = 'whatiwanttoecho';
echo $result;
```

Hope this makes sense. Thanks (:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GHi,

Try the example from this code:

```
$doccontents = 'blahhh result.php?whatiwanttoecho blah blah blah';
$rgxp = '/result.php\?([^ ]+)/i';
if(preg_match($rgxp, $doccontents, $mc)) $result = $mc[1];
else $result = 'No match';
echo $result;      // whatiwanttoecho
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE | E_NOTICE);
$string= 'blah blah result.php?whatiwanttoecho blah';
$string= 'blahhh result.php?whatiwanttoecho blah blah blah';
preg_match_all('/result\.php\?([.\w\W]*?)[\s\n]/ui', $string, $matches);
foreach(end($matches) as $key=> $value){
    print '<pre>'.print_r($value, 1).'</pre>';
}
```

Comment: If the string ends with `result.php?whatiwanttoecho` your regex don't match (also see [this link](http://ideone.com/FC4p1)).

Comment: Sorry, but contrary to CoursesWeb solution your regex still doesn't match if `result.php?whatiwanttoecho` is at the end of the string (also see [this link](http://ideone.com/jer3B)).

Answer (score 0):

How about first exploding the full string in two parts using `$array =explode("?",$fullstring,2)` and then exploding the 2nd part of the string with `$urstring = explode(" ",$array[1],2)` and finally echoing the string u want `echo $urstring[0];`??
Hope this solves ur problem